# Go Modules - Local package(s) not accessible?

Tags: go, module

So, I'm new to Go. I've created a go.mod file

`module github.com/austin/test-project` <--- This is all I've added to the go.mod

I added a tag v0.0.1 to my commit latest git commit.

Based on some examples I tried to understand, I added these imports to my go file(s), where *common* is one package, *dynamo* is another, and the import is from a third package called *main*.

```
import (
"github.com/austin/test-project/common"
"github.com/austin/test-project/db/dynamo/playerstateddb"
"github.com/austin/test-project/db/dynamo/characterstateddb"


"context"
"fmt"
"encoding/json"

"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
"github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
```

And here is my output after running `go build ./handler/characterstate`
 where the *main* go file is:

```
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events latest
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda latest
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute latest
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb latest
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws latest
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session latest
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go v1.7.0
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go v1.7.0
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service latest
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.15.89
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.15.89
go: finding github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath v0.0.0-20160202185014-0b12d6b521d8
go: downloading github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath v0.0.0-20160202185014-0b12d6b521d8
```

The go.mod file is now this:

```
module github.com/carbonated-dev/madworld-backend

require (
    github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go v1.7.0
    github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.15.89
)
```

... and I have a characterstate.exe at the root, and the expected go.sum

In my IDE, GoLand, the import paths for my local *common* and *dynamo* packages are still highlighted red.

I've been searching all day, and I've got no idea what's going on. Where am I going wrong? Could it be that the git repo is private that I'm trying to

Thanks in advance. Hope to hear from someone soon :)

Comment: A) As you found out the semver does _not_ belong into the import path (only major versions like "v2" go there so please edit your question and remove the obvious wrong stuff. B) You did not show your go.mod. Always include all relevant information in the question. C) You said "didn't let me set the version to v0.1" which is correct if your project exists only in version v0.01 as you said earlier. D) WHat is the reason to play with _experimental_ features of Go if you are super fresh to Go?

Comment: @Volker
A) Done.
B) Added comment... as that one line was my go.mod
C) Okay
D) This doesn't help my problem.

I may be misinterpreting, but I was picking up a certain tone from your comment, one that sits on the side of not-so-nice. If I'm wrong, then ignore. If I'm right, can we stick to being courteous and helpful, or just not post anything at all?

Comment: Okay. Now it seems as if there is no more error while building you project, or? So what is the question? All seems to be fine. For D) Modules are an experimental feature. It is dead unlikely that they will change much but nevertheless they are experimental and your IDE might not support them jet. So why play hard and use them? There is a reason why the official How to Write Go Code description does not mention modules.

Comment: @Volker You were 100% right... at least from what I found out a couple hours ago. After doing more research, the thought popped into my head (partly thanks to your previous comment) that since this is a new feature, maybe my IDE doesn't support, and if so I should check for the latest version to see if it does. My version of GoLand didn't support it, but the latest version does and the imports are just fine now.

Thanks for your help. Is there a way to close this out since I answered my own issue? Or is it proper to answer your own question on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply and outdated IDE. Once updated to a version that supported Go 1.11, I no longer saw the red error text on import.